# I need help with arrow in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like a symmetrical arrow pointing to the other circle in this Venn diagram, but can't figure it out.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgflibraryarrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{venn circle/.style={draw,circle,minimum 
width=6cm,fill=#1,opacity=0.4,text opacity=1}}

 \node [venn circle = gray] (A) at (0,0) {$Virginia$};
 %\node [venn circle = white] (B) at (60:4cm) {$Ohio$};
 \node [venn circle = gray] (C) at (0:5cm) {$Ohio$};
 %\node[left] at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,B=1/2 ) {}; 

 \node[below] at (barycentric cs:A=1/3 ) (endpoint) {};
 \node[below] at (barycentric cs:C=1/3 ) (endpoint) {};
 \draw[*-angle 60] 
 ( [yshift=-10pt] $ (A.south)!0.5!(C.south) $ ) node[anchor=north] {\{  
Virginia \emph{or} Ohio \}}
to[bend right,looseness=1.5] 
(endpoint.south east);


\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make you example compilable. I get `No shape named B is known.`.

Comment: Why is the node `endpoint` defined twice? you may have to change one of those to another name.

Comment: barycentric with only one point it's strange ! The code is too complicated ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: two arrows]

The following has been edited to incorporate Alain Matthes's comments.

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}% is the recommended library
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    venn circle/.style={draw,circle,minimum width=6cm,fill=#1,opacity=0.4,text opacity=1},
    >/.tip={Straight Barb[angle=60:3pt 3]},
  ]

  \node [venn circle = gray] (A) at (0,0) {$Virginia$};
  %\node [venn circle = white] (B) at (60:4cm) {$Ohio$};
  \node [venn circle = gray] (C) at (0:5cm) {$Ohio$};
  %\node[left] at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,B=1/2 ) {};

  \node[below] at (A.center) (endpoint A) {};
  \node[below] at (C.center) (endpoint C) {};
  \node [circle, fill, minimum size=5pt, inner sep=0pt] (either) at ( [yshift=-10pt] $ (A.south)!0.5!(C.south) $ ) {};
  \draw[->] (either) to[bend right,looseness=1.5] (endpoint C.south east);
  \draw[->] (either) to[bend left,looseness=1.5] (endpoint A.south east);
  \node [anchor=north] at (either) {\{ Virginia \emph{or} Ohio \}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `-angle 60` seems to be not defined in arrows.meta. I'm not sure of the utility of endpoint A and C.

Comment: That works. Thank you very much. Tikz is decidedly not my strong suit.

Comment: @AlainMatthes Do you know what the equivalent is? Usually, I just update the syntax, but in this case I wasn't sure what I was trying to do. About the endpoints, the lines need somewhere to point, correct? So you want something inside the circle and below the label. There are other ways to do it, of course. You could just use `A.center` and `C.center` with `yshift` or something.

Comment: @AlainMatthes I don't know what the `barycentric` does, though.

Comment: @cfr For the arrow I don't know because I have not yet read the new manual perhaps something like Triangle [angle = 60 ...] About endpoint I think that the center of circles are enough because the definition of endpoint with barycentric are wrong. Barycentric coordinates define a point from several points (>2) with coefficients ex A,.5 and B,.5 define the middle. Here endpoint is perhaps A ?

Comment: @AlainMatthes Thanks. Please see edit. I think `Straight Barb` is probably the best choice of arrow tip in terms of matching. `Triangle` would use a triangle, which is not what the OP had. (Unless you want to change them to triangles, of course. Then `Triangle` would be perfect.) I don't think the use of `barycentric` violates TikZ's definition. It is just pointless as it will always end up being just the `center` anchor if only one node/coordinate is specified.